# Explicit isomorphism of algebras $\mathbb C[S_3]\cong \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \times M_2(\mathbb C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\mathbb C[S_3]$ be the group algebra of $S_3$. We have an isomorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras
$$\mathbb C[S_3]\cong \mathbb C \times \mathbb C \times M_2(\mathbb C).$$

The existence of such an isomorphism is not difficult to show using [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem). Moreover, one can show using character theory, as done, e.g., in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484314/representations-of-the-symmetric-group-s-3), that this decomposition corresponds precisely to the (iso classes of) irreducible representations of $S_3$. However, how does one construct an *explicit* isomorphism between $\mathbb C[S_3]$ and its decomposition, as $\mathbb C$-algebras?

I do know that one copy of $\mathbb C$ corresponds to the trivial representation, one copy corresponds to the sign representation, and the matrix algebra $M_2(\mathbb C)$ corresponds to the "standard" representation. I also know that elements in $\mathbb C[S_3]$ have the form $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq 6}\lambda_i \sigma_i$ for some $\lambda_i \in \mathbb C$ and $\sigma_i \in S_3$. I also think this decomposition above into irreducible factors is somehow related to primitive idempotents? However, I'm not sure how to start constructing an explicit isomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by Lukas Heger of course settles all finite groups at once.
Still, for $S_3$ it is very possible to give an explicit hands-on description of this map.

Such an isomorphism is essentially nothing more than writing out the decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[S_3]$ into primary components explicitly. This is not too difficult to do: For notation, let $\tau$ be any nontrivial 3-cycle (so that $A_3=\{1,\tau, \tau^2\}$) and $\sigma$ be any transposition.

The subspace of fixed points of $\mathbb{C}[S_3]$ is just $T$, the line of all vectors with constant coefficients, i.e. all multiples of the vector $\sum_{g\in S_3}g$.

Similarly, the subspace $S$ corresponding to the sign representation can be easily determined to be all multiples of the vector
$$1+\tau+\tau^2-\sigma(1+\tau+\tau^2),$$
i.e. all those vectors that have equal coefficients on any coset of $A_3$ but overall coordinate sum of $0$. (This can for instance be determined from the observation that both the sign and the trivial representation are fixed by $A_3$ - hence both components must lie in the subspace of $A_3$-fixed points, which are just the multiples of $1+\tau+\tau^2$.)

Thus, the last remaining component is the four dimensional invariant complement of $T\oplus S$, which is just
$$V=\left \{ x\in \mathbb{C}[S_3]:\sum_{g\in A_3}x_g g=\sum_{g\in \sigma A_3}x_g g=0   \right \}. $$

These three subspaces $T,S$ and $V$ are now exactly your desired $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{C}$ and $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. The isomorphism from $\mathbb{C}[S_3]$ can then be read off from the projection onto these subspaces (i.e. primary idempotents). These can be cleanly written in terms of $u=\frac{1}{3}(1+\tau+\tau^2)$: The idempotent in $T$ is $e_T=\frac{u+\sigma u}{2}$, in $S$ we have $e_S=\frac{u-\sigma u}{2}$ and for $V$ we have the complementary
$$e_V=1-e_T-e_S=1-u.$$
Altogether this explicitly determines the algebra isomorphism
$$\mathbb{C}[S_3]\to T\times S\times V, x\mapsto (e_Tx,e_Sx,e_Vx).$$

The further identifications $T\simeq S\simeq \mathbb{C}$ are of course canonical, while $V\simeq M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is determined only up to isomorphism, which is essentially a choice on how to split $V$ further into two complementary $S_3$-invariant subspaces. I will leave it to you to figure out a specific such isomorphism.

Comment: Does taking $\sum_{g\in S_3}\operatorname{sgn}(g)\cdot g$ also work for the subspace corresponding to the sign representation? (Here $\operatorname{sgn}(g)\in \{\pm 1\}$.)

Comment: Yes, that is the same element (and the idempotent $e_S$ is a sixth of it).

Answer (score 4):

There's a explicit isomorphism for every  finite group $G$.

Let $V_1, \ldots, V_n$ be a complete set of representatives of the irreducible representations up to isomorphism with $\rho_i:G \to \operatorname{GL}(V_i)$ the defining homomorphism.

Then the map
$$\Bbb C[G] \to \prod_i \mathrm{End}(V_i)$$ sending $g \mapsto (\rho_i(g))_i$ is the desired isomorphism of algebras.

This is related to harmonic analysis of finite groups. A reference is *Representation Theory of Finite Groups* by B. Steinberg.

Comment: $\operatorname{End}$ here just means vector space endomorphisms. Choosing a basis for $V_i$ induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(V_i) \cong M_{n_i}(\Bbb C)$ with $n_i$ being the dimension of $V_i$.

Comment: Thank you. This explanation combined with the reference should help me figure out the explicit maps for the case of $\mathbb C[S_3]$.